# SoapUI Interface Glitch 23.10

Tags: networking, gui

After updating Ubuntu to 23.10, my SoapUi interface began to have a weird glitch.

This a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody have a clue why this happens? I tried different JDK versions but nothing worked. I found somewhere that it may be related to the J2D_D3D that should be turned to false, but i have no idea where to find this parameter.

Comment: Perhaps Wayland? Try if it also happens on an Xorg session. Edit your question and include information about your desktop environment and your hardware, in particular graphics card. Note also that not a lot of people may be familiar with the software you refer to (I am not at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found something that helped me. Maybe it can be useful for others too:

https://9to5answer.com/how-to-fix-fontconfig-error-failed-reading-config-file

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge fontconfig-config
sudo apt install fontconfig-config
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
```